# Transformation amount locked

Tags: animation, transforms

Every time I try to animate my rig, the amount I can move the arrow transformation is fixed so I can't make any small adjustments.
[image]

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is because you have **Increment Snapping** enabled. to solve, simply disable this function by clicking on the little magnet at the bottom of the screen or hitting <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>.

[image]

Comment: you can hold [shift] to move with smaller snapping increments.